# Why does this "count" function not work? (PHP/MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, count, boolean, full-text-search

I have a php/mysql script which doesn't function! I need to find out how many rows of a string does exist and i have to count from an "boolean full text" function.

this is the code which doesn't function:

```
$resuslt=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(homeid) 
                       FROM notes 
                       WHERE MATCH(title, text, tags) AGAINST('+$searchstring*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS accurate 
                       FROM notes 
                       WHERE MATCH(title, text, tags) AGAINST ('+$searchstring*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```

What should i do?

Comment: Try to avoid using `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).** What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect.  A single select can only have one `from`.  It is also unclear what your intention is.

Comment: it's not working because you have syntax errors and absolutely NO error handling. at the very bare minimum you should have `$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`. Never assume success.

Comment: What you should do is [check for errors](http://php.net/mysql_error). And stop using deprecated extensions (it could not be more clearly stated in the documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(homeid) 
FROM notes 
WHERE MATCH(title, text, tags) AGAINST('+$searchstring*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0;
```

If `homeid` could be repeated, you might really want `count(distinct homeid)`.

Answer (score -1):

Is this supposed to be a subselect? if not you have two From's in there:

```
"SELECT COUNT(homeid) 
                       FROM notes 
                       WHERE MATCH(title, text, tags) AGAINST('+$searchstring*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS accurate 
                       FROM notes 
                       WHERE MATCH(title, text, tags) AGAINST ('+$searchstring*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```

You could try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(homeid) 
                           FROM notes 
                           WHERE MATCH(title, text, tags) AGAINST('+$searchstring*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AS accurate
                           FROM notes 
                           WHERE MATCH(title, text, tags) AGAINST ('+$searchstring*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```